# Hacking Attempts Following a Poisson Process

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Hacking attempts of a particular website occur according to a Poisson process with an average of $5$ minutes between each attempt.

The cyber security team of the website decided to install an update at $9$:$10$:$00$PM that would take $30$ seconds to complete, however, they needed to take down the firewall to complete this update. The security team discovers at $9$:$10$:$30$PM that one hacking attempt did occur at some time while the firewall was down. What is the probability that this hacking attempt occurred between $9$:$10$:$20$PM and $9$:$10$:$30$PM?

I'm particular confused with this question. Of the two options below, I'm not sure which I should use.

Namely,

(1) $A_t \sim $***Pois***$(\frac{1}{300})$ where $A_t$ is the number of hacking attempts in time $t$ (seconds) and,

(2) $T \sim $***Exp***$(\frac{1}{300})$ where $T$ is the time $t$ (seconds) between hacking attempts.

I feel like it should be (1), however, I'm not entirely sure.

If it were (1) I would include the following working,

$\begin{align}Pr(A_{620} = 0 | A_{630} = 1) & =  \dfrac{Pr(A_{620} = 0, A_{630} = 1) }{Pr(A_{630} = 1)}\\ &=  \dfrac{Pr(A_{10} = 1)\cdot Pr(C_{620} = 0)}{Pr(A_{630} = 1)} \\ &=\dfrac{e^{-\frac{10}{300}}\big(\frac{10}{300}\big)\cdot e^{-\frac{620}{300}}}{e^{-\frac{630}{300}}\big(\frac{630}{300}\big)}\\ & = 0.0159
\end{align}$

How can I tell which one is the correct distribution to choose. If my choice of (1) is correct, is my working ok? If not, where can I improve?

Answer (score 0):

Let $\tau=\inf\{t:A_t>0\}$. Conditioned on $A_{30}=1$, the distribution of $\tau$ is uniform over $(0,30)$ and therefore the desired quantity $\mathbb P(20<\tau<30)$ is $1/3$.

Alternatively, We may compute the probability of $\{A_{30}-A_{20}=1\}$ conditioned on $\{A_{30}=1\}$ as follows:
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(A_{30}-A_{20}=1\mid A_{30}=1) &= \frac{\mathbb P(A_{30}-A_{20}=1, A_{30}=1)}{\mathbb P(A_{30}=1)}\\
&= \frac{\mathbb P(A_{30}-A_{20}=1)}{\mathbb P(A_{30}=1)}\\
&=\frac{e^{-\frac1{300}\cdot10}\left(\frac1{300}\cdot10\right)}{e^{-\frac1{300}\cdot30}\left(\frac1{300}\cdot30\right)}\\
&= \frac13.
\end{align}

Comment: In the second line above your last line (last line being $\frac{1}{3}$), how did you get strictly $\Pr(A_{30} - A_{20})$ in the numerator? Was it because that $A_{30} - A_{20} = 1)$ is a subset of the event $A_{30} = 1$

Comment: @Philip Yes, that is correct. More formally,
$$\{A_{30}-A_{20} = 1\}\subset \{A_{30}=1\},  $$ hence
$$\{A_{30}-A_{20} = 1\}\cap\{A_{30}=1\}  = \{A_{30}-A_{20} = 1\}.$$